# oracle find and add prefix and suffix to a substring in varchar2 column

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

We want to find and add different prefix and suffix to a substring in varchar2 column.I have provided example string.I want to find and add prefix and suffix to substring

`"<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">this is atable of content macro</ac:structured-macro>"`

and change it to

`<ac:structured-macro ac:name="scroll-ignore" ><ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">this is atable of content macro</ac:structured-macro></ac:structured-macro>`

example column string:
"{toc:outline=true|printable=false}

`<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">this is a table of content macro</ac:structured-macro>`

Results Viewing allows the clinician to review Laboratory, Radiology, and Vital Signs results within a patient context. This allows the clinician to have the most recent results available for their patient."

I tried using regex replace but couldn't do it in single query

`update bodycontent set body=REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '(<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">)',
'<ac:structured-macro ac:name="scroll-ignore"> <ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">')
where contentid=716785`

`update bodycontent set body=REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '(<\/ac:structured-macro>)',
'</ac:structured-macro></ac:structured-macro>',1,1)
where contentid=716785`

Comment: flagged as very low quality as question doesn't show any effort

Comment: please change the quality i have updated the statement.

Comment: OP showed effort and edited the question. I think the question is not unclear and should not be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is easier to understand if you simplify your examples a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE bodycontent (body VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR));
INSERT INTO bodycontent VALUES ('<foo>text</foo>');
SELECT * FROM bodycontent;
<foo>text</foo> 

UPDATE bodycontent SET body = REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '(<foo>.*</foo>)', 
    '<bar>\1</bar>');

SELECT * FROM bodycontent;
<bar><foo>text</foo></bar>
```

Is that ok? If so, your real data would look like:

```
INSERT INTO bodycontent VALUES (
   '<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">'||
   'this is atable of content macro</ac:structured-macro>');


UPDATE bodycontent SET body = REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '(<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">.*</ac:structured-macro>)', 
     '<ac:structured-macro ac:name="scroll-ignore">\1</ac:structured-macro>');

SELECT * FROM bodycontent;
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="scroll-ignore">
   <ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">
     this is atable of content macro
   </ac:structured-macro>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!